# Stream.Read on exe files

Tags: vb.net

I'm porting this piece of C code to VB.net. The function `cat` receives a pointer to a file, reads it and rewrites it into the console (works the same way as the `TYPE` command from DOS). My vb implementation works well for all types of files, except exe files, in which case, writes a lot more of "text" than what actually is in the exe file.

This is the C code:

```c
enum {
    BSIZE = 8192
};

int
cat(FILE *f)
{
    char buf[BSIZE];
    int n;

    while((n = fread(buf, 1, BSIZE, f)) > 0)
        if(fwrite(buf, 1, n, stdout) != n)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

And this is the vb code:

```vb
Public Const BSIZE As Integer = 8192

Function cat(ByVal f As Stream) As Integer
    Dim buf(BSIZE) As Byte
    Dim n As Integer

    Do
        n = f.Read(buf, 0, BSIZE)
        Try
            Console.OpenStandardOutput.Write(buf, 0, n)
        Catch ex As IOException
            Return 0
        End Try
    Loop While n > 0

    Return 1
End Function
```

For example, I used the C-exe of the program as the file to read. The C version writes about 10 lines of unintelligible characters, while the VB version writes more than 70; among these, I've noticed something interesting:

> P§@ Mingw runtime failure:    VirtualQuery failed for %d bytes at
>   address %p      Unknown pseudo relocation protocol version %d. Unknown
>   pseudo relocation bit size %d.    GCC: (tdm-1) 5.1.0  GCC: (tdm-1)
>   5.1.0  GCC: (tdm-1) 5.1.0  GCC: (tdm-1) 5.1.0

It looks like the Stream.Read method is reading more than what it should read. Why is this happening?

Comment: This is not likely related to your issue but `Dim buf(BSIZE) As Byte` should be `Dim buf(BSIZE - 1) As Byte`.

Comment: The basic explanation for the difference in behavior is that the C code interprets the binary data differently than .NET code. You're using two completely different run-time libraries, which will interact with the console window differently and treat the raw binary data as different text encodings. More to the point though: a binary file, like a .exe, **is not text**. It is meaningless to just write the binary data to the console as if it were. You need to decide on some heuristic for deciding what in the binary file should be treated as text, and then filter as you read.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926097/replace-strings-in-native-exe-using-c-sharp for useful details. I wouldn't exactly call your question a duplicate, but it's nearly so.

Comment: More for my interest, exactly what is the use case for printing binaries?